# how to pass a datagridview value after double clicking to a textbox on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, datagridview

Im working on a complex ribbon application, so far it is going well but now I have a litle tricky situation where I have to pass value of a DataGridView to a `TextBox` on another `Form` after double clicking the the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options actually. And it all depends on the code/architecture of your application, but generally what you are looking for are delegates.
here is an introductory level article for delegates: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/03/02/c-delegates-actions-lambdas-keeping-it-super-simple.aspx) is a link to some basic examples which will introduce you to Actions and Lambdas as well.

Or, if those two Forms can see each other (if you have references for both forms in one parent), you can create an event on the source form and subscribe to it on the destination form, and pass the data in that manner.

***The Source Form:***

*• Define the delegate*

```
public delegate void RibbonDataHandler(string);
```

*• Define the event*

```
public event RibbonDataHandler RibbonData;
```

*• Define the method to execute the event*

```
protected virtual void OnRibbonData( string value )
{
    if( RibbonData != null )
        RibbonData( value );
}
```

• Invoke the event on the *DoubleClick* event handler of the *DataGridView*

```
string value = // Get Value from the gridView
OnRibbonData( value );
```

***The Destination Form:***
• Add a public property to set the *TextBox* value

```
public string TextBoxValue
{
    get { return txtValue.Text; }
    set { txtValue.Text = value; }
}
```

***The Parent Form:***

• add those two forms as fields

```
private Form _sourceForm;
private Form _destinationForm;
```

• Initialize the forms

```
// Well, initialize the forms in the way you need it, maybe on the Load event?
_sourceForm = new SourceForm();
_destinationForm = new DestinationForm();
_sourceForm.RibbonData += new SourceForm.RibbonDataHandler(OnRibbonData);
```

• Define the RibbonData Handler

```
private void OnRibbonData( string value )
{
    _destinationForm.TextBoxValue = value ?? String.Empty;
}
```

***Disclaimer:***
I wrote all of this out of my head, did not have VS at this moment, if you have more questions or if something is not working, leave a comment. :)